# Periodically resolving a promise in javascript

Tags: javascript, promise, setinterval

Let’s say I want to resolve some promise every 2 seconds AFTER the function is run.

I tried a pattern like this at first: `setInterval(MyAsyncFunction, 2000)`, but of course this does not wait for the promise to resolve before calling the function again.

I also tried `setInterval(async () => await MyAsyncFunction(), 2000)`, but this is basically the same thing since I’m just wrapping it in another promise that will resolve while the setInterval is ticking down.

Is there a way to do what I am trying to do with setInterval or is there some alternative way to do this using setTimeout?

Comment: can you share your code

Comment: What do you mean to have a promise resolve every 2 seconds? The whole purpose of promises is to handle not knowing how long something needs to run. If we do know how long something is going to run – 2 seconds – why does it need to be in a promise?

Comment: A promise is resolved at most once. You'd need something else, like an observable. But if what you actually want to do is to simply *call a function* every two seconds, just put it in a loop with an `await delay(2000)` in it.

Comment: cal setTimeout from that function to itself. This way it will be started only when function is done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Promise resolves once only, so therefore cannot, by definition, resolve periodically.

If you define a delay function, which returns a promise that resolves after `timeout` ms...

```
const delay = timeout => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, timeout));
```

you could use it in an async loop:

```
async function foo(){
    for(let i = 0; i < 100; ++i){
        console.log("azrael");
        await delay(2000);
    }
}
```

Comment: this is same as setInterval. Probably question is not that clear, but I think, what author wants is to wait for async function, then wait extra time, than repeat. So it will not call async function every 2s, but will call it AFTER 2s from the previous call finished.

Answer (score -1):

If what you want is to call async function, then await for it, then wait extra fixed time, then repeat, you may approach it following ways.

You can call setTimeout from that function itself, so it will schedule its next run when it's finished:

```javascript
async function myAsyncFunction() {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => {
    resolve('result');                       // resolves, then
    setTimeout(async () => {                 // schedules
      let result = await myAsyncFunction();  // self-call
      console.log('result')                  // and handles the result
    }, 2000);                                // after extra 2s
  }, 2000));          // imitates async function with 2s delay
}

async function main() {
  let firstResult = await myAsyncFunction();
  console.log(firstResult);  // handles first call
}
```

More clean way is to wrap it in another async function with same setTimeout inside:

```javascript
async function myAsyncFunction() {
  // imitates async function
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve('result'), 2000));
}

async function delayLoop() {
  let result = await myAsyncFunction();  // waits for it
  console.log(result);
  setTimeout(delayLoop, 2000); // calls itself after extra 2s
}

delayLoop();
```

This way you do not have to modify original async function code and put callback right in there.

Both examples will await for async function for 2s before first result, and for 4s between calls - 2s async function delay + 2s extra delay after it.